# web-bluetooth get stored data from device GATT

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

My goal is to get data stored in device.

Like device which is measuring temp or whatever and store it to its memory. i need to query all this data device has via Record Access Control Point (RACP).

1. First thought, to achieve it, was

   - get characteristic
   - start notifications
   - write code to descriptor
   - get all data via eventListener

result: throws error on starting notifications
examples used:

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/notifications-async-await.html
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=664863

2. Next thought was to not starting notification since characteristic is 
   INDICATE, WRITE type.
   So was thinking about add listener and write to descriptor code from device docs which states:

> OP Code:
>   1 – Report stored records

even with deleted startNotifications line is throwing error
so my code example is:

```
const mainService = 'my correct service uuid';
    const characteristicUUID1 = 'my correct char uuid';
    const characteristicUUID2 = 'my correct char uuid';
    const descriptorUUID = '00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
    let deviceCache = null;
    let serverCache = null;
    let serviceCache = null;
    let characteristicCacheA = null;
    let characteristicCacheB = null;
    let descriptorCache = null;

    try {
      deviceCache = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ name: 'my device' }] });

      console.log('Connecting to GATT Server...');
      serverCache = await deviceCache.gatt.connect();

      console.log('Getting Services...');
      serviceCache = await serverCache.getPrimaryService(mainService);

      console.log('Getting Characteristics A...');
      characteristicCacheA = await serviceCache.getCharacteristic(characteristicUUID1);

      console.log('Start Notifications A...');
      await characteristicCacheA.startNotifications();

      console.log('Getting Characteristics B...');
      characteristicCacheB = await serviceCache.getCharacteristic(characteristicUUID2);

      console.log('Start Notifications B...');
      await characteristicCacheB.startNotifications();

      console.log('Add event listener...');
      characteristicCacheA.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', this.handleNotifications);

      console.log('Getting Descriptor...');
      descriptorCache = await characteristicCacheA.getDescriptor(descriptorUUID);

      console.log('Write value to descr...');
      await descriptorCache.writeValue(new Uint8Array([1]));


    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message, 'error');
    }
```

Error with notifications is(with experimental chrome features it doesn't throw error):

> error: GATT operation failed for unknown reason.

Error with descriptor is:

> writeValue() called on blocklisted object marked exclude-writes.

Also my device is asking for pin but web is connecting without prompting anything. And so maybe it says that writing to descriptor is blocked.

How to handle pin input - no clue(once i got prompt to enter pin after enabling chrome experimental features not sure if its related).

Is my logic correct? - dont think so.

Any suggestions?

What i have investigated so far?

1. https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/
2. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch04.html
3. https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/

Edit: After reading this article - https://medium.com/@devdevcharlie/experimenting-with-web-bluetooth-1f1176047ddd

I think correct logic should be, write to command characteristic commands you need(like get all data). After that find correct characteristic responsible for this data from device docs, and start notifications and add eventListener and receive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now, chrome is not able or got issues with communicating with protected characteristics on windows 10, on macOS it is all working perfectly. I have posted issue on chromium bug tracker if someone is in to watching it.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=960258#c6

Answer (score 1):

The call to `writeValue()` is failing because access to the CCCD is [on the blocklist](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/registries/blob/master/gatt_blocklist.txt#L54). The call to `startNotifications()` will write to the descriptor as necessary to enable notifications.

We need to investigate this "unknown reason" for `startNotifications()` failing. What operating system are you using? Please follow the instructions for [reporting Web Bluetooth bugs](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs) and file an issue in the Chromium project's issue tracker.

Comment: After i have switched here chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features enabled experimental features enabled, i startNotifications is now triggering fine but i thought it was supposed to work either way. 
I am using latest Chrome and macOS.   

Ok, so i dont have to write value to descriptor correct? 
How am i suppose to say to characteristic to give me data stored? 
also according to docs i can get records or records count etc depending on OP codes. So i assume i should write this code to somewhere. To characteristic or where?

Comment: got this in console:   



default 10:39:48.549322 +0300 bluetoothd ***** [handleATTErrorResponse].
error

10:39:48.549444 +0300 bluetoothd ***** [handleATTErrorResponse] - Insufficient Authentication.
default

10:39:48.549615 +0300 bluetoothd ***** [handleATTErrorResponse] - Link is not encrypted, perform pairing with MITM disbled.